# sending image from popover to parent view

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a view that opens another view Controller as popover

the popover uses an image picker and displays the chosen image in an imageView.
The parent also has an imageView with an IBoutlet named profiler and before dismissing the popover i would like the parent view to get the chosen image.

How would i go about accessing parent and sending the image from the popover to the parent view

below is code from the popover view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        picker.delegate = self



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }





    //MARK: - Delegates
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
        myImageView.image = chosenImage //4


        myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        myImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.height/4
        myImageView.clipsToBounds = true



        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) //5
    }
```

thanks for any help rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback closure, it's less effort than delegate/protocol

- In the popover view controller add a property

  ```
  weak var callback : ((UIImage) -> ())?
  ```
- Call it in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` before `dismiss`

  ```
  callback?(chosenImage)
  ```
- In the parent view controller after creating the controller add

  ```
  popoverViewController.callback = { image in
      // do something with the image
  }
  ```

`popoverViewController` is the popover view controller instance

Comment: how does this approach called? I've never seen something like this before. Really would like to read a bit more about passing closures between viewcontrollers

Comment: Oh come on ;-). This is a quite common pattern in Swift (even in Objective-C). The closure works like a function whose reference is passed. The child view controller executes the closure in the parent view controller returning the image.

Comment: yeah, got it, but shouldn't some of these be `weak`? `callback` itself, or `self` inside closure?

Comment: @JuicyFruit Yes, indeed. However `self` is not involved in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

you should create protocol

```
protocol PopOverImagePickerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didSelect(image: UIImage)
}
```

inside your `PopoverViewController` create

```
weak var delegate: PopOverImagePickerDelegate?
```

before navigating to `PopoverViewController` from `ParentViewController` set

```
popOverViewController.delegate = self
```

and then create

```
extension ParentViewController: PopOverImagePickerDelegate {
    func didSelect(image: UIImage) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

and when image picked inside `PopoverViewController` just call

```
self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)
```